# TypeError: init_app() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_domain when to install flaskbb

Tags: python, flask

I have installed many  things as http://www.flaskbb.org/first_steps.html   step by step.
When I use `python manage.py createall` I get an error:

```
/home/test/test/flaskbb# python manage.py createall

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "manage.py", line 44, in <module>  
    app = create_app(Config)  
  File "/home/test/flaskbb/flaskbb/flaskbb/app.py", line 63, in create_app  
    configure_extensions(app)    
  File "/home/test/flaskbb/flaskbb/flaskbb/app.py", line 141, in   configure_extensions   
    babel.init_app(app=app, default_domain=FlaskBBDomain(app))  
TypeError: init_app() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_domain'
```

I try it the second time with another account.

```
root@debian:/home/debian# pip install -U flask-babelex
Requirement already up-to-date: flask-babelex in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: Flask in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask-babelex)
Requirement already up-to-date: Babel>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask-babelex)
Requirement already up-to-date: speaklater>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask-babelex)
Requirement already up-to-date: Jinja2>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask-babelex)
Requirement already up-to-date: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask->flask-babelex)
Requirement already up-to-date: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask->flask-babelex)
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz>=0a in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Babel>=1.0->flask-babelex)
Requirement already up-to-date: markupsafe in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.5->flask-babelex)
root@debian:/home/debian/flaskbb/flaskbb# python manage.py createall
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 44, in <module>
    app = create_app(Config)
  File "/home/debian/flaskbb/flaskbb/flaskbb/app.py", line 63, in create_app
    configure_extensions(app)
  File "/home/debian/flaskbb/flaskbb/flaskbb/app.py", line 141, in configure_extensions
    babel.init_app(app=app, default_domain=FlaskBBDomain(app))
TypeError: init_app() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_domain'
```

Same problem remain,have you tried to install flaskbb in your local machine?
Success or failure?

```
root@debian:~# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask.ext.babelex
>>>
```

I can import it ,maybe other problem result in the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have forked the extension and submitted a pull request but it's still unmerged.. for now you have to install it from this repository: https://github.com/sh4nks/flask-babelex

You can do it like this:

`pip install https://github.com/sh4nks/flask-babelex/tarball/master#egg=Flask-BabelEx`

You can also to upgrade the whole dependencies if you want:

`pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade`

PS: FlaskBB is not finished yet - but I appreciate every help! :)

Comment: I missed that your fork moved the `default_domain` parameter to `init_app()`.